# Что не даёт входной ноде Tor расшифровать трафик

Tags: http, https, шифрование, tor

я изучал то, как работает Tor. Как я понял трафик проходит через три узла (Ноды). Входная нода знает откуда пришел трафик, но не знает что в нем, потому что он зашифрован. А выходная наоборот, не знает откуда он пришел. Но я не могу понять что не даёт входной ноде расшифровать трафик, так же как это делает выходная?

Comment: Вынесите суть вопроса в название, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Трафик может идти больше чем через 3 ноды.
- Ноды работаю, как  прокси.

Первая не может расшифровать, ибо это "вход в лабиринт", если бы она расшифровывала, то знала что за трафик идёт, к ней были претензии у полиции, ибо этот узел публичен.

Промежуточные, это обычный анонимный прокси.

Точка выхода, что отдаёт вам трафик, уже знает что это за трафик. Соответственно она в "зоне риска".

Так что технически, это возможно, но смысл TOR теряется.

Comment: Что означает что узел публичен? Ведь если он начнет расшифровывать трафик то никто об этом не узнает? Или люди пользуются Tor исключительно на вере в то, что входная нода не скомпроментирована и не имеет доступа к трафику и IP его источника?

Comment: через этот публичный узел и происходит обращение к искомому ресурсу.  Если он просто проксирует трафик , то претензий к нему нету.

компрометация ноды(устройства, и т.п.) и веры в её отсутствие, это краеугольный камень всей ИТ безопасности.